# What's happening when I make changes in project that is a dependecy of a jar?

Tags: java, jar, build

I have problem to fully understand jar. I have two projects, project two is added to build path of project one (it's a dependency). From project one I created a jar. After creating jar, I made changes in project two. Does jar see/use this changes(made in project two),or do I need to build that jar once more ? And why it see or don't see does changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would have added the project itself to the BuildPath then you don't have to do anything and all your changes made to the project will be available to your dependent project.

But as you said you have added the JAR and not the source, you'll have to compile your project, create the JAR and then add it to your other project.

Comment: I added project two (not a jar but a source of project) to BuildPath of project one ,then made a jar of project one. So from what you have written, I guess, I don't need to worry about building jar of project one once more. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Majlena If you have added the project in the BuildPath then your dependent project will get the updates whenever something changes in the other project. For local development/testing it is okay. But even then you might have to rebuild your JAR for distribution depending on how you are packaging it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you export your jar file.

If the jar file contains only the classes of project one(jarA), you do not need to rebuild that jar once more. But you need to make a jar from project two(jarB) and when you execute the jarA, you need to add the jarB to the class path(I think this is the way you chose).

If the jar file contains both project classes(jarAB),you need to rebuild that jar,and when executing the jar,you do not need to make a jarB because the jarAB contains classes of project two.